# Why are Shadows immune to Repulsing Seal?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

I used a *Repulsing Seal* trap on some Shadows. "Immune" popped up above their heads when it went off, and in the battle logs at the bottom right, I see their Fortitude defence show up as "Imm.":

[image: Screenshot showing "Acc:32 - Fort.:Imm. = Imm.. when I hover over a Repulsing Seal Trap miss]

I'm puzzled by why. I know that the Fighter's *Knock Down* ability works on Shadows, which - like Repulsing Seal - is also a "vs. Fortitude" ability that causes Prone. The Bestiary page for Shadows clearly shows a finite Fortitude defence and doesn't show any immunity to Prone. So what's going on? Is this a bug? A hidden special-case immunity just to Repulsing Seal that isn't indicated anywhere in the Bestiary? Or have I missed something in the Bestiary that should've clued me in to this immunity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shadows are immune to Ground effects.

Comment: Hmm. I suspect this is indeed the explanation, although it's a bit confusing since *Repulsing Seal* is not marked as a Ground effect in its description (unlike some other abilities like the *Scroll of Tanglefoot* which is labelled "Ground" right at the top of its description). Repulsing Seal meets the definition in the Cyclopedia of a Ground attack, though, so I guess the bug here is in the description of Repulsing Seal (which ought to label it as "Ground").